# In Angular, Navigation makes a component disappear

Tags: html, angular, angularjs

I use a html template, and I try to make it works in angular, I have make everything right, and now I do the routing, but actually, when I navigate to another component, there is a child component doesn't show up some elements tag, and when I back to the previous page, the header component disappear but when I open the devtools to see what happening, I see that the component is still there, so what the problem?

both the component have a image content. but actually there is a image content in another components, and it works.

**slider.component.html**:

```html
<div id="rev_slider_two" class="rev_slider fullscreenbanner" style="display:none;" data-version="5.4.1">
  <ul>

      <!-- SLIDE 1 -->
      <li data-index="rs-70" data-transition="fade" data-slotamount="default" data-hideafterloop="0" data-hideslideonmobile="off"  data-easein="default" data-easeout="default" data-masterspeed="300"  data-thumb="assets/images/1.png"  data-rotate="0"  data-saveperformance="off"  data-title="" data-param1="1" data-param2="" data-param3="" data-param4="" data-param5="" data-param6="" data-param7="" data-param8="" data-param9="" data-param10="" data-description="">
          <!-- MAIN IMAGE -->
          <img src="assets/images/1.png" data-bgcolor='rgba(255,255,255,0)' alt="" data-bgposition="center center" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat" data-bgparallax="off" class="rev-slidebg" data-no-retina>

          <!-- LAYER 1  right image overlay dark-->


          <!-- LAYER 3  Thin text title-->
          <div class="tp-caption tp-resizeme caption-big-2"
              id="slide-70-layer-1"
              data-x="['center','center','center','center']" data-hoffset="['0','0','0','0']"
              data-y="['center','center','center','center']" data-voffset="['-38','-30','-30','-18']"
              data-fontsize="['150',142','110','70']"
              data-lineheight="['150','130','110','70']"
              data-fontweight="['200','200','200','200']"
              data-color="['#fff','#fff','#fff','#fff']"
              data-whitespace="nowrap"

              data-type="text"
              data-responsive_offset="on"

              data-frames='[{"delay":0,"speed":1000,"frame":"0","from":"x:50px;opacity:0;","to":"o:1;","ease":"power3.inOut"},{"delay":"wait","speed":1000,"frame":"999","to":"x:50px;opacity:0;","ease":"power3.inOut"}]'

              data-textAlign="['center','center','center','center']"

              >Live Minimalism
          </div>

          <!-- LAYER 4  Bold Title-->
          <div class="tp-caption   tp-resizeme tp-desc-2"
              id="slide-70-layer-6"
              data-x="['center','center','center','center']" data-hoffset="['0','0','0','0']"
              data-y="['center','center','center','center']" data-voffset="['60','58','50','35']"
              data-fontsize="['18','18','16','16']"
              data-lineheight="['20','20','16','16']"
              data-color="['#fff','#fff','#fff','#fff']"
              data-letterspacing="['8','8','8','8']"
              data-fontweight="['300','300','300','300']"
              data-whitespace="nowrap"

              data-type="text"
              data-responsive_offset="on"

              data-frames='[{"delay":0,"speed":1000,"frame":"0","from":"x:50px;opacity:0;","to":"o:1;","ease":"power3.inOut"},{"delay":"wait","speed":1000,"frame":"999","to":"x:50px;opacity:0;","ease":"power3.inOut"}]'

              data-textAlign="['left','left','left','left']"

              >controlling all the details and consulting the builders
          </div>

          <!-- LAYER 5  Paragraph-->
          <div class="tp-caption tp-resizeme"
              id="slide-70-layer-3"
              data-x="['left','left','left','left']" data-hoffset="['15','15','15','15']"
              data-y="['top','top','top','top']" data-voffset="['420','279','271','235']"
              data-fontsize="['18','18','22','16']"
              data-lineheight="['30','34','32','28']"
              data-whitespace="nowrap"

              data-type="text"
              data-responsive_offset="on"

              data-frames='[{"delay":2900,"speed":1000,"frame":"0","from":"x:50px;opacity:0;","to":"o:1;","ease":"power3.inOut"},{"delay":"wait","speed":1000,"frame":"999","to":"x:50px;opacity:0;","ease":"power3.inOut"}]'

              data-textAlign="['left','left','left','left']"

              >
          </div>

          <!-- LAYER 6  Read More-->
          <div class="tp-caption rev-btn"
              id="slide-70-layer-4"
              data-x="['left','left','left','left']" data-hoffset="['15','15','15','15']"
              data-y="['top','top','top','top']" data-voffset="['525','385','370','320']"
              data-lineheight="['18','18','16','16']"
              data-width="none"
              data-height="none"
              data-whitespace="nowrap"
              data-responsive_offset="on"

              data-frames='[{"delay":3400,"speed":1000,"frame":"0","from":"x:50px;opacity:0;","to":"o:1;","ease":"power3.inOut"},{"delay":"wait","speed":1000,"frame":"999","to":"x:50px;opacity:0;","ease":"power3.inOut"}]'

              data-textAlign="['center','center','center','center']"
              data-paddingtop="[0,0,0,0]"
              data-paddingright="[0,0,0,0]"
              data-paddingbottom="[0,0,0,0]"
              data-paddingleft="[0,0,0,0]"

              >
          </div>

      </li>


      <!-- SLIDE 1 -->
      <li data-index="rs-71" data-transition="fade" data-slotamount="default" data-hideafterloop="0" data-hideslideonmobile="off"  data-easein="default" data-easeout="default" data-masterspeed="300"  data-thumb="assets/images/3.jpg"  data-rotate="0"  data-saveperformance="off"  data-title="" data-param1="1" data-param2="" data-param3="" data-param4="" data-param5="" data-param6="" data-param7="" data-param8="" data-param9="" data-param10="" data-description="">
          <!-- MAIN IMAGE -->
          <img src="assets/images/3.jpg" data-bgcolor='#ffffff' alt="" data-bgposition="center center" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat" data-bgparallax="off" class="rev-slidebg" data-no-retina>


          <!-- LAYER 3  Thin text title-->
          <div class="tp-caption tp-resizeme caption-big-2"
              id="slide-71-layer-3"
              data-x="['center','center','center','center']" data-hoffset="['0','0','0','0']"
              data-y="['center','center','center','center']" data-voffset="['-38','-30','-30','-18']"
              data-fontsize="['150',142','110','70']"
              data-lineheight="['150','130','110','70']"
              data-fontweight="['200','200','200','200']"
              data-color="['#fff','#fff','#fff','#fff']"
              data-whitespace="nowrap"

              data-type="text"
              data-responsive_offset="on"

              data-frames='[{"delay":0,"speed":1000,"frame":"0","from":"x:50px;opacity:0;","to":"o:1;","ease":"power3.inOut"},{"delay":"wait","speed":1000,"frame":"999","to":"x:50px;opacity:0;","ease":"power3.inOut"}]'

              data-textAlign="['center','center','center','center']"

              >Oasis in Desert
          </div>

          <!-- LAYER 4  Bold Title-->
          <div class="tp-caption tp-resizeme tp-desc-2"
              id="slide-71-layer-6"
              data-x="['center','center','center','center']" data-hoffset="['0','0','0','0']"
              data-y="['center','center','center','center']" data-voffset="['60','58','50','35']"
              data-fontsize="['18','18','16','16']"
              data-lineheight="['20','20','16','16']"
              data-color="['#fff','#fff','#fff','#fff']"
              data-letterspacing="['8','8','8','8']"
              data-fontweight="['300','300','300','300']"
              data-whitespace="nowrap"

              data-type="text"
              data-responsive_offset="on"

              data-frames='[{"delay":0,"speed":1000,"frame":"0","from":"x:50px;opacity:0;","to":"o:1;","ease":"power3.inOut"},{"delay":"wait","speed":1000,"frame":"999","to":"x:50px;opacity:0;","ease":"power3.inOut"}]'

              data-textAlign="['left','left','left','left']"

              >new level of interior and exterior design for house
          </div>

          <!-- LAYER 5  Paragraph-->
          <div class="tp-caption   tp-resizeme"
              id="slide-71-layer-7"
              data-x="['left','left','left','left']" data-hoffset="['15','15','15','15']"
              data-y="['top','top','top','top']" data-voffset="['420','279','271','235']"
              data-fontsize="['18','18','22','16']"
              data-lineheight="['30','34','32','28']"
              data-whitespace="nowrap"

              data-type="text"
              data-responsive_offset="on"

              data-frames='[{"delay":2900,"speed":1000,"frame":"0","from":"x:50px;opacity:0;","to":"o:1;","ease":"power3.inOut"},{"delay":"wait","speed":1000,"frame":"999","to":"x:50px;opacity:0;","ease":"power3.inOut"}]'

              data-textAlign="['left','left','left','left']"

              >
              </div>

          <!-- LAYER 6  Read More-->
          <div class="tp-caption rev-btn"
              id="slide-71-layer-8"
              data-x="['left','left','left','left']" data-hoffset="['15','15','15','15']"
              data-y="['top','top','top','top']" data-voffset="['525','385','370','320']"
              data-lineheight="['18','18','16','16']"
              data-width="none"
              data-height="none"
              data-whitespace="nowrap"
              data-responsive_offset="on"

              data-frames='[{"delay":3400,"speed":1000,"frame":"0","from":"x:50px;opacity:0;","to":"o:1;","ease":"power3.inOut"},{"delay":"wait","speed":1000,"frame":"999","to":"x:50px;opacity:0;","ease":"power3.inOut"}]'

              data-textAlign="['center','center','center','center']"
              data-paddingtop="[0,0,0,0]"
              data-paddingright="[0,0,0,0]"
              data-paddingbottom="[0,0,0,0]"
              data-paddingleft="[0,0,0,0]"

              >
          </div>
      </li>

      <!-- SLIDE 1 -->
      <li data-index="rs-72" data-transition="fade" data-slotamount="default" data-hideafterloop="0" data-hideslideonmobile="off"  data-easein="default" data-easeout="default" data-masterspeed="300"  data-thumb="assets/images/2.jpg"  data-rotate="0"  data-saveperformance="off"  data-title="" data-param1="1" data-param2="" data-param3="" data-param4="" data-param5="" data-param6="" data-param7="" data-param8="" data-param9="" data-param10="" data-description="">
          <!-- MAIN IMAGE -->
          <img src="assets/images/2.jpg" data-bgcolor='#ffffff'  alt="" data-bgposition="center center" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat" data-bgparallax="off" class="rev-slidebg" data-no-retina>


          <!-- LAYER 3  Thin text title-->
          <div class="tp-caption tp-resizeme caption-big-2"
              id="slide-72-layer-3"
              data-x="['center','center','center','center']" data-hoffset="['0','0','0','0']"
              data-y="['center','center','center','center']" data-voffset="['-38','-30','-30','-18']"
              data-fontsize="['150',142','110','70']"
              data-lineheight="['150','130','110','70']"
              data-fontweight="['200','200','200','200']"
              data-color="['#fff','#fff','#fff','#fff']"
              data-whitespace="nowrap"

              data-type="text"
              data-responsive_offset="on"

              data-frames='[{"delay":0,"speed":1000,"frame":"0","from":"x:50px;opacity:0;","to":"o:1;","ease":"power3.inOut"},{"delay":"wait","speed":1000,"frame":"999","to":"x:50px;opacity:0;","ease":"power3.inOut"}]'

              data-textAlign="['center','center','center','center']"

              >Dream House
          </div>

          <!-- LAYER 4  Bold Title-->
          <div class="tp-caption   tp-resizeme tp-desc-2"
              id="slide-72-layer-6"
              data-x="['center','center','center','center']" data-hoffset="['0','0','0','0']"
              data-y="['center','center','center','center']" data-voffset="['60','58','50','35']"
              data-fontsize="['18','18','16','16']"
              data-lineheight="['20','20','16','16']"
              data-color="['#fff','#fff','#fff','#fff']"
              data-letterspacing="['8','8','8','8']"
              data-fontweight="['300','300','300','300']"
              data-whitespace="nowrap"

              data-type="text"
              data-responsive_offset="on"

              data-frames='[{"delay":0,"speed":1000,"frame":"0","from":"x:50px;opacity:0;","to":"o:1;","ease":"power3.inOut"},{"delay":"wait","speed":1000,"frame":"999","to":"x:50px;opacity:0;","ease":"power3.inOut"}]'

              data-textAlign="['left','left','left','left']"

              >our philisophy in simply and quality design
          </div>

          <!-- LAYER 5  Paragraph-->
          <div class="tp-caption   tp-resizeme"
              id="slide-72-layer-7"
              data-x="['left','left','left','left']" data-hoffset="['15','15','15','15']"
              data-y="['top','top','top','top']" data-voffset="['420','279','271','235']"
              data-fontsize="['18','18','22','16']"
              data-lineheight="['30','34','32','28']"
              data-whitespace="nowrap"

              data-type="text"
              data-responsive_offset="on"

              data-frames='[{"delay":2900,"speed":1000,"frame":"0","from":"x:50px;opacity:0;","to":"o:1;","ease":"power3.inOut"},{"delay":"wait","speed":1000,"frame":"999","to":"x:50px;opacity:0;","ease":"power3.inOut"}]'

              data-textAlign="['left','left','left','left']"

              ></div>

          <!-- LAYER 6  Read More-->
          <div class="tp-caption rev-btn"
              id="slide-72-layer-8"
              data-x="['left','left','left','left']" data-hoffset="['15','15','15','15']"
              data-y="['top','top','top','top']" data-voffset="['525','385','370','320']"
              data-lineheight="['18','18','16','16']"
              data-width="none"
              data-height="none"
              data-whitespace="nowrap"
              data-responsive_offset="on"

              data-frames='[{"delay":3400,"speed":1000,"frame":"0","from":"x:50px;opacity:0;","to":"o:1;","ease":"power3.inOut"},{"delay":"wait","speed":1000,"frame":"999","to":"x:50px;opacity:0;","ease":"power3.inOut"}]'

              data-textAlign="['center','center','center','center']"
              data-paddingtop="[0,0,0,0]"
              data-paddingright="[0,0,0,0]"
              data-paddingbottom="[0,0,0,0]"
              data-paddingleft="[0,0,0,0]"

              >
          </div>
      </li>


  </ul>

</div>
```

I tried to lazy loading the image, but it didn't work.
I thought that is a caching problem, but it doesn't.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `style="display:none;` from the first `div` element